# PlotlyJS rotate ellipse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly.js

Is there a way to rotate the ellipse in PlotlyJS? To draw a circle/ellipse in Plotly, you define the center and the radii in the positive and negative x and y directions. Is there a way to define an angle at which the ellipse is rotated around its center or perhaps defining the 4 outermost points of the ellipse instead perhaps rather than having plotly deducing them through the radii values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "manually" construct the points of the ellipse:

```js
var center_x = 0;
var center_y = 0;
var a = 3; // major radius
var b = 1; // minor radius
var alpha = Math.PI / 4; // angle of rotation;
var X = [];
var Y = [];
var npoints = 100;
for(var i = 0; i <= npoints; i++) {
  var t = 2 * Math.PI * i / npoints;
  var x = a * Math.cos(t);
  var y = b * Math.sin(t);
  X.push(center_x + Math.cos(alpha)*x - Math.sin(alpha)*y);
  Y.push(center_y + Math.sin(alpha)*x + Math.cos(alpha)*y);
}
```

Then plot it with a `line` type.

Comment: I assume you meant var t =  2 * Math.PI / i otherwise this generates one data point only npoint times.
Even then the resulting shape will not be an ellipse (more like half an ellipse closed with straight lines not a curve)

Comment: @MohamedYehia Sorry. `2 * Math.PI * i / npoints`. I edit.